# How read json local file with jquery with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I have js only project.
i call from my static index.html file the json file content.

I try(not works):

```
 $.getJSON('/js/test.json&callback=?',
   function() {
    alert('1111111111111111');
 },'jsonp');
```

Edit get in chrome:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///somefolder/test/data.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Thanks

Comment: why the (&callback=?) looks wrong!

Comment: the callback should be used for JSON-P requests

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve json from a local source, it doesn't need to be jsonp, and even if it did what you are doing is not how you do it.

```
$.getJSON('http://yours.com/js/test.json',
   function() {
   alert('1111111111111111');
});
```

Comment: not working! i use jsonp because i access local file without server that run it.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///somefolder/test/data.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: The file has to be on the same domain as the request.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing data variable in callback!

```
$.getJSON('/js/test.json', function(data) {
    console.log('JSON data received:', data);
});
```

Comment: not working! i use jsonp because i access local file without server that run it.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///somefolder/test/data.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.